# Sending a Array from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

Hi Im trying to send an array from php to my javascript. Is this possible? Ive tryied a few examples that Ive found but non of them have worked.

Here is what Im trying to do:

php file:

```
<?php
$n = array('test','test2', 'test3');
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    initArray($n);
</script>
?>
```

javascipt:

```
function initArray(array){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        alert(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Thx for all your answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php 
$n = array('test','test2', 'test3'); 
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var arr = <?php echo json_encode($n); ?>; // create the JavaScript array
    initArray(arr); // use it
    function initArray(array){
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            alert(array[i]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

You need to use [**`json_encode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert a PHP array to a JavaScript one, and output its result while assigning it to a JavaScript variable.

Comment: @Linqan: Great! If my answer solved your problem, feel free to accept it by clicking the empty tick below the vote counts on the left side of my answer to make it green, which will mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 3):

You have to serialize it. Try it with JSON. http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: Ive never used JSON. Is that the only way?

Comment: Not the only, but I guess is the best. Take a look at this example. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php